# Sum the Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: c, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
    int i=0,j,k,l,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(i<=100000&&i>0){
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        scanf("%d",&k);
        if(k<=1000000000&&k>0){
        for(l=3;l<k;l++){
            if(l%3==0||l%5==0)
                {sum+=l;}
        }}
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    sum=0;
    }}
```

The above code does satisfy all the test cases but it has been rejected citing that it is very slow. Please suggest improvements to the code.

Comment: The formatting makes it nearly unreadable.  Code that doesn't look good also typically doesn't run well.

Comment: Hint: you don't need loops at all.  How would you find out _how many_ multiples of `3` (or `5`, but let's stick with one term for the moment) there were?  What stunt did `Gauss` do as a young student that's applicable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51093/finding-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000)

Comment: @sds: That question is from a different user and about a different language.  Such questions are not considered duplicates on Code Review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, try to think about the problem before brute-forcing it.

Is there an easy way to sum all the multiples of 3 below \$N\$? Of course there is. 
First we note that the largest multiple of 3 is \$3 * \lfloor\frac{N}{3}\rfloor\$ and the sum of all the multiples is then \$3 * 1 + 3 * 2 + ... 3 * \lfloor\frac{N}{3}\rfloor\$. Factor out the 3 and you get \$3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + ... \lfloor\frac{N}{3}\rfloor)\$. Now we use Gauss's trick for summing the natural numbers to get a nice easy formula for the sum: \$3*x*\frac{x+1}{2}\$, where \$x\$ is \$\lfloor\frac{N}{3}\rfloor\$.

Similarly, we can get the sum for the multiples of 5, and add the results together. However, we then have a bunch of duplicates (namely multiples of 15)
which we can also calculate in a similar manner and then subtract to get the final result.

This approach completely eliminates any and all looping, and so will be super quick.

Now, let's discuss your code. Here's a list of suggestions:

1. If you are prompting the user, provide some helpful hints as to what you are expecting as input.
2. Having hardcoded bounds such as yours is unintuitive. Have your sum be a long or even long long (depending on the desired platform) and you will not run into issues with integer inputs, which are guaranteed by `scanf(%d)`. This will also cut down on the indentation, increasing readability.
3. Variable names are important. While it is pretty easy to see that `i`, `k` are the bounds, and `j`, `l` are counter variables after reading the code, it would be even easier to understand with `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` and `i`, `j` for the counters (per standard practices).
4. Consider generalizing the problem to create a function that will be reusable elsewhere.

Comment: Use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to generalize the code for any list of divisors.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with one for loop. The % operator is predefined for numeric types to compute the remainder after division. So if the remainder after division is 0 then you can add "i" to "sum".

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < 1000; i++)
{
   int value1 = i%5 == 0?5:0;
   int value2 = i%3 == 0?3:0;
   sum += (value1 + value2) >0 ?i:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple problem to get the answer. Just use the A.P and the answer will be:

(sum of multiple of 3) + (sum of multiple of 5) - (sum of multiple of 15)

Use this formula to calculate the sum = n(a + l) / 2, where n = number of terms.

- a = first term
- l = last term

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This site is a bit different from the other Stack Exchange Q&A sites - here answers are expected to *review* the OP's code; please see [what makes a good CR-ish answer](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1990/23788) on our Meta for more details.